# InvalidImageSize Microsoft Face API 1.0

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

This one beats me try everything such as base64  converting it into binary just keep getting this error below

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidImageSize","message":"Image size 
 is too small or too big."}}
```

here is my code is written in python :

```
import httplib, urllib, base64
import json
import sys
import base64


# require for authentication 
key = "YourKey" 
# leave as one header so ther three steps can access the same format
# application/octet-stream
headers = {
# Request headers
'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
}
# params for detection  return FaceId 
params = urllib.urlencode({
# Request parameters
'returnFaceId': 'true',

})

with open("C://Python-Windows//random_test//unknowfaces//Adam.jpg", "rb") as 
imageFile:
f =  imageFile.read()
b = bytearray(f)

  print f


   #image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)



   """
   body = {
     "url":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-
   dKxIImkT0to/WApnOYQSIFI/AAAAAAAAAAA/H9IsZ2xGxiE/photo.jpg"
  }

  """
  #below is for the binary 
  body = {
     f[0]
   }

 # conn to be use at all three steps 
  conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
  conn.request("POST", "/face/v1.0/detect?%s" % params, str(body), headers)
  response = conn.getresponse()
 data = response.read()
 print(data)

 #Parse json data to print just faceId
 somedata = json.loads(data)
 faceid = somedata[0]['faceId']

 print  somedata[0]['faceId']

 print " :is what face id has produce ==> " + faceid
 conn.close()
```

not sure if I have intended the above code properly on this tread  so do please check.

I would appreciate your support thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you might change your code:

```
with open("your-image.jpg", "rb") as imageFile:
  image = imageFile.read()
  conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
  conn.request("POST", "/face/v1.0/detect?%s" % params, headers=headers, body=image)
  response = conn.getresponse()
  data = response.read()
  print(data)
  conn.close()
```